# creating Polygon from LineString and a width

Tags: geotools, polygon-creation

I have to create a Polygon from a lineString and a width. Ex: Given a street as a lineString (Or a list of points) and a width, create the polygon (the road). I am using Geotools, but I couldn't find anything helpful in the API.

The math for doing this manually is requiring to much work. Is there a simpler solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried buffer ? http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/operation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and quick reply. The buffer should do the trick. It was exactly what I was looking for.